# Javascript onclick event on getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

I have a svg map and I am putting that into object and I am trying to create all path with id clickable.

For that I am doing this to get svg object :

```
 let a = document.getElementById("biharsvg")
```

And I am putting that into svg doc like this:

```
   var svgDoc = a.contentDocument;
```

And now I am getting all the values of certain class using this:

```
  let de = svgDoc.getElementsByClassName("fil0");
```

I can also get the attribute id value using this:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < de.length; i++) {
  var j = de[i].getAttribute("id");
   console.log(j);

}
```

I want to add a click event on each attribute id and get the value when I am doing this:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < de.length; i++) {
  var j = de[i].getAttribute("id");
   console.log(j);
  svgDoc.getElementById(j).onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "block";  
        console.log(this.getAttribute("id"));
    }
}
```

This is working fine and I am getting all the values but in jquery I can use this:

```
 $(de).click(function(){
   alert(this.getAttribute("id"));
});
```

Is there any way I can use something like this in javascript without loop. My question is what is the best possible way to make this work in javascript.

Comment: No there isn't. Why not use jQuery?

Comment: I am trying to understand can I do this in plain javascript without loop

Comment: No you can't. Why not use jQuery?

Comment: Well the basic principle of _event delegation_ “works” in vanilla JS as well, if you want to avoid having to add an individual handler to each single element.

Comment: jQuery also uses a loop, if you write `$(de).click(` then jQuery internally loops over all element in the result set create by `$(de)` and attaches the given event handler to each of these elements, they just _"hide"_ it in their code.

Comment: @user2480754 The answer to your question, which is regarding the return value of `getElementsByClassName()` is "no", but you can add a click listener to a common parent, then check `e.target` where `e` is the parameter of the handler function.

Comment: Can't you just do `de.forEach(el => {el.onclick = function{ /*do whatever*/}; })` ? Or even in your loop `de[i].onclick = function(){/* do sth*/}`? It still uses loop but looping through array of dom element to get its id and then grabbing the same element by id looks like overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript version for jQuery's

```
$(de).click(function(){
   alert(this.getAttribute("id"));
});
```

would be something like

```
Array.from(de).forEach( function(el){
    el.addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert(this.getAttribute("id"));
        // or "this.id" should work too
    });
});
```

*To be noted, when doing `$(de).click(function(){...}` with jQuery, it also loops, internally.*

---

And as commented, with [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) you could shorten the code even more

```
Array.from(de).forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', function () {...}))
```

```js
var de = document.querySelectorAll('span');

Array.from(de).forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', function () {
  alert(this.id);
}))
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
span::after {
  content: attr(id)
}
```

```html
<span id="nr1">click </span>
<span id="nr2">click </span>
<span id="nr3">click </span>
```

---

Updated based on a comment.

The main difference between your existing loop and the above is, the above is more efficient, with a cleaner/shorter code.

In your original loop

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < de.length; i++) {
  var j = de[i].getAttribute("id");
   svgDoc.getElementById(j).onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "block";  
        console.log(this.getAttribute("id"));
    }
}
```

you iterate through the element array `de`, get its `id` and then make a new call using `getElementById` to get the element you already have.

With the kept syntax/logic, your existing code could been simplified to something like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < de.length; i++) {
    de.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";  
        console.log(this.getAttribute("id"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it the same thing which I am doing inside my loop or it is different or better version. Need explanation

Comment: So with an extra line of javascript, and you can drop a 240kb library ... seems like a good trade to me :)

Comment: @user2480754 It is a more efficient and cleaner/shorter way to loop an array of e.g. elements, your existing `for..loop` does the same job though

Comment: @Pete Of course (updated with a note)...were focusing on the `forEach` vs jQuery internal loop

Comment: @user2480754 I updated my answer with an explanation. Let me know if it made sense.

Comment: Thanks for  answering

Answer (score 0):

I just want to show an alternative way, pointed out by CBroe, where a click on the document is checked for its event target:

```js
let de = Array.from(mylist.getElementsByClassName("fil0"));
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const el = e.target;
  if (de.indexOf(el) < 0) return false;
  alert(el.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<ul id="mylist">
  <li>one</li>
  <li class="fil0">two*</li>
  <li class="fil0">three*</li>
</ul>

<p>* has click event assigned indirectly</p>
```

This has the additional benefit that it only uses a single handler function, and if the `indexOf()` condition is changed to something like `classList.contains()`, it will even work for elements that don't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

I find `for..of` to be the most convenient and readable syntax:

```
for (const element of svgDoc.getElementsByClassName("fil0")) {
  console.log(element.id);
}
```